# Set user status at Facebook

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I have a game application released at the Facebook platform. I need to set the user status who played the game so that after the user playing the game and scoring high score, I need to set the status of the user to be showed in the home page of the user so his/her friends can share the action of playing the game with him/her and can challenge each other.

I am using an Iframe application using [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) and C# language. I have used the Facebook service and called the code

```
_fbService.users.setStatus("Message");
```

and it reports an error saying:

> Updating status requires the extended permission status_update

so how can I solve this problem? I need to do like other games, that after playing the game and achieving a noticable action in the game to be showed at the status of the user in the home page and be shared with his friends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to request an extended permission from the user in order to make use of a whole bunch of FB functionality - including setting the user status.

It's pretty easy to do, info can be found here:

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Extended_permissions

Comment: i have followed this link and found that i have to use :
FB.Connect.streamPublish and the problem now where to put this method in the .cs file or on in the javascript ?
i have tried it in the <script> section but nothing !! and what will intialize it to be pop up to the user to allow access and give permissions? can u help me please? i need real example that i can use it directly in asp,net application and thanks

Comment: In your javascript... something like:


Facebook.showPermissionDialog('status_update',ondone);
function ondone(){
 document.location("Invite.aspx")
}


This would ask the user for status update permissions, then when they return from the dialogue, will redirect them to an invite page...

Good luck fella